# Display latest entry from different mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have three tables products, events with same date of creation column 'creation'. But if any user add entry to any table, details should be displayed from that specific row on webpage.
Can you suggest me, how to do it?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1` what's the problem?

Comment: Since you have 3 tables, make a union in a subquery, then use `ORDER BY` in the main query to get the latest out of all 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT col1, col2, date
      FROM table1
      ORDER BY date DESC
      LIMIT 1
      UNION
      SELECT col1, col2, date
      FROM table2
      ORDER BY date DESC
      LIMIT 1
      UNION
      SELECT col1, col2, date
      FROM table3
      ORDER BY date DESC
      LIMIT 1) u
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: He said he just wants to display the latest one, so it's needed. The union returns 3 rows.